# How do I read and update HttpResponse body using PipeWriter?

Tags: .net-core-3.0

This is actually a 2-part question related directly to .net core 3.0 and specifically with PipeWriter: 1) How should I read in the HttpResponse body? 2) How can I update the HttpResponse? I'm asking both questions because I feel like the solution will likely involve the same understanding and code.

Below is how I got this working in .net core 2.2 - note that this is using streams instead of PipeWriter and other "ugly" things associated with streams - eg. MemoryStream, Seek, StreamReader, etc.

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate Next { get; }
    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) => Next = next;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var httpResponse = context.Response;
        var originalBody = httpResponse.Body;
        var newBody = new MemoryStream();
        httpResponse.Body = newBody;

        try
        {
            await Next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // In this scenario, I would log out the actual error and am returning this "nice" error
            httpResponse.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            httpResponse.ContentType = "application/json"; // I'm setting this because I might have a serialized object instead of a plain string
            httpResponse.Body = originalBody;
            await httpResponse.WriteAsync("We're sorry, but something went wrong with your request.");
            return;
        }

        // If everything worked
        newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var response = new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEnd(); // This is the only way to read the existing response body
        httpResponse.Body = originalBody;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
    }
}
```

How would this work using PipeWriter? Eg. it seems that working with pipes instead of the underlying stream is preferable, but I can not yet find any examples on how to use this to replace my above code?

Is there a scenario where I need to wait for the stream/pipe to finish writing before I can read it back out and/or replace it with a new string? I've never personally done this, but looking at examples of PipeReader seems to indicate to read things in chunks and check for IsComplete.

Answer (score 0):

To Update HttpRepsonse  is

```
 private  async Task WriteDataToResponseBodyAsync(PipeWriter writer, string jsonValue)
        {
            // use an oversized size guess
            Memory<byte> workspace = writer.GetMemory();
            // write the data to the workspace
            int bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
               jsonValue, workspace.Span);
            // tell the pipe how much of the workspace
            // we actually want to commit
            writer.Advance(bytes);
            // this is **not** the same as Stream.Flush!
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Is there any restrictions on using this method - eg. If you already have an httpResponse, or if the jsonValue is large, etc? And how would you read from the response?